# Sass mixin @content not letting grids working properly

Tags: html, sass, scss-mixins

I'm having an odd issue, I'm new to using the `@mixin` and `@content` tag, and sass in general for that matter, but for some reason, my `grid-template-areas` don't accurately represent what I want them to.

HTML

```
<header>
 <div class="text"></div>
 <nav>
   <div class="about"></div>
   <div class="qualities"></div>
   <div class="portfolio"></div>
   <div class="contact"></div>
 </nav>
</header>
```

SCSS

```
$colors: (
    red: red,
    blue: blue
);

@function border($color) {
  @return 3px map-get($colors, $color) solid;
}

@mixin desktop {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    @content;
  }
}

header {
    grid-area: header;
    border: border(red);

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "header-title nav";

    .text {
      grid-area: header-title;
      border: 3px green solid;
    }

    nav {
      grid-area: nav;
      border: border(blue);
    }

    @include desktop {
      grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
      grid-template-areas: "header-title header-about header-q header-port header-contact";

      .about {
        grid-area: header-about;
        border: border(blue);
      }

      .qualities {
        grid-area: header-q;
        border: border(blue);
      }

      .portfolio {
        grid-area: header-port;
        border: border(blue);
      }

      .contact {
        grid-area: header-contact;
        border: border(blue);
      }

    }

  }
```

To see this issue... [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1a23sh8e/3/)

It should go from splitting the header into 2 columns to splitting the header into 5 columns;

Comment: It does, but the `.header` only has two child elements ?

Comment: How? The classes are included in the @include, you know, about, qualities, portfolio, contact?

Comment: The `media-querie` is applied on `header` which only has 2 direct childs and not 5. Because `.about`, `.qualities`, etc. are nested in `nav`, they are not affected by the `header`'s `grid-template-areas`.